Mysql group by MIN(price)
I have a table filled with pre-calculated prices for rental objects. This is a simple version of it:
CREATE TABLE `pricecache` (
  `oid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `start` date NOT NULL,
  `end` date NOT NULL,
  `duration` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `guests` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `child` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `animal` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stamp` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `pricecache` (`oid`, `start`, `end`, `duration`, `guests`, `child`, `animal`, `price`, `stamp`) VALUES
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 1, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 2, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 3, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 4, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 5, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 6, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 1, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 2, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 3, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 4, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 5, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 6, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-03', '2023-11-10', 7, 1, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-03', '2023-11-10', 7, 2, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-03', '2023-11-10', 7, 3, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-03', '2023-11-10', 7, 4, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-03', '2023-11-10', 7, 5, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-03', '2023-11-10', 7, 6, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-04', '2023-11-11', 7, 1, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),

Here is the complete file
I want to get the lowest price each day and the number of objects which have that price. I tried this:
SELECT oid, ROUND(MIN(price)/duration, 0) xprice
FROM `my_cache`
WHERE `price` > 0
GROUP BY ROUND(price/duration, 0)
ORDER BY `xprice` ASC

but this way I still see redundant/ungrouped xprice values.
I want to display the data as a price filter similar to airbnb:

How can I do this?

Why does your sample data have duplicate rows? Is there something important you're not showing here? Also, please replace pictures with formatted text in addition to showing your desired output as formatted text.

Please read here how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@Isolated there is nothing missing.

They why is each row duplicated 10 times in your table? That makes no sense.

So you mean the source table? There are other rows, like timebased or number of guests but they are not relevant for this query.

@maidan Please stop writing comments, remove the comments again. Edit your question to add further information. And as said, your question misses the expected result.

It doesn't make sense to group a query by the value you're aggregating. GROUP BY is used to tell it which rows should be considered a group to find the minimum among them.

You probably want GROUP BY oid. And it should be MIN(price/duration) -- you can't mix aggregated and non-aggregated columns.

@Barmar I did SELECT MIN(price/duration) at first, but that way i don't get the lowest price.

What is the expected result? And could you show data that has multiple groups? All your sample data is for the same oid.

It also doesn't make sense to use SELECT * in a grouped query. All the non-aggregated columns will just pick a random row within each group. You should get an error if the SQL mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is set.

@Barmar I will update the question tomorrow

SELECT * ... GROUP BY does not make sense.  Please learn how to use GROUP BY.

The sample data is not meaningful, because all the prices and date ranges are the same.

@JoelCoehoorn Checkout the whole data i linked.

Nope. That's not how things work here. We don't have to time to dig trough large files like that, and even if we did, you're the one who needs answers. Why should each person who might help need to repeat that work, when the asker can do it once for everyone?  So it's on you to give us a meaningful sample set of at most 20-ish rows. Also, the dropbox link doesn't work for if we don't have an account anyway. It's okay, though, if the first attempt isn't quite there. That's why we have an edit option.

Well 20 rows is too little to represent what's happening here. So i thought showing a big sample file can help understand the question better. And you dont need Dropbox to download the file.

UPDATED ANSWER:
Used just a part of your data (slightly changed):
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
INSERT INTO `pricecache` (`oid`, `start`, `end`, `duration`, `guests`, `child`, `animal`, `price`, `stamp`) VALUES
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 1, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 2, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 3, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 4, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 5, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-08', 7, 6, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 1, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 2, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 3, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 4, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 5, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1162, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 6, 0, 0, 679, '2023-10-27 17:00:02'),
(1173, '2023-11-05', '2023-11-12', 7, 1, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-05', '2023-11-12', 7, 2, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-05', '2023-11-12', 7, 3, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-05', '2023-11-12', 7, 4, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-05', '2023-11-12', 7, 5, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-05', '2023-11-12', 7, 6, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 1, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 2, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 3, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 4, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 5, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1173, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-09', 7, 6, 0, 0, 1120, '2023-11-18 14:05:05'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 1, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 2, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 3, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 4, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 5, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 6, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 7, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 8, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 9, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-01', '2023-11-15', 14, 10, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 1, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 2, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 3, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 4, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 5, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 6, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 7, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 8, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 9, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01'),
(1160, '2023-11-02', '2023-11-16', 14, 10, 0, 0, 10752, '2023-11-27 13:00:01')

Create a calendar for the period of interest using recursive cte:
WITH 
   RECURSIVE cal AS 
    ( SELECT (Select Min(START) From pricecache) AS DAY_ID 
    UNION ALL 
      SELECT DAY_ID + interval 1 day 
      FROM cal 
      WHERE DAY_ID <= (Select Max(END) From pricecache)
   ),

... another cte geting min prices per date, object and duration
  prices AS
   ( Select     c.DAY_ID, p.OID, p.DURATION, 
                  Min(p.PRICE) "MIN_OBJECT_AMOUNT_FOR_DURATION",
                  Round(Min(p.PRICE) / p.DURATION, 2) "MIN_OBJECT_PRICE_PER_NIGHT"
      From       cal c
      Inner Join pricecache p ON(p.START <= c.DAY_ID And p.END >= c.DAY_ID)
      Group By   c.DAY_ID, p.OID, p.DURATION
      Order BY   c.DAY_ID, p.OID, p.DURATION
    )

... use it self joined to get min price for every day and number of objects having that min price for that day
--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT p.DAY_ID, p.MIN_PRICE_PER_NIGHT, Count(Distinct p2.OID) "NUM_OF_MINPRICED_OBJECTS"
FROM ( SELECT p.DAY_ID,  
              Min(p.MIN_OBJECT_PRICE_PER_NIGHT) "MIN_PRICE_PER_NIGHT"
       FROM prices p
       GROUP BY p.DAY_ID
       ORDER BY p.DAY_ID
   ) p
INNER JOIN prices p2 ON(p2.DAY_ID = p.DAY_ID And
                        p2.MIN_OBJECT_PRICE_PER_NIGHT = p.MIN_PRICE_PER_NIGHT)
GROUP BY   p.DAY_ID, p.MIN_PRICE_PER_NIGHT
ORDER BY   p.DAY_ID, p.MIN_PRICE_PER_NIGHT

/*    R e s u l t :
DAY_ID       MIN_PRICE_PER_NIGHT   NUM_OF_MINPRICED_OBJECTS
----------   -------------------   ------------------------
2023-11-01                    97                          1
2023-11-02                    97                          1
2023-11-03                    97                          1
2023-11-04                    97                          1
2023-11-05                    97                          1
2023-11-06                    97                          1
2023-11-07                    97                          1
2023-11-08                    97                          1
2023-11-09                    97                          1
2023-11-10                   160                          1
2023-11-11                   160                          1
2023-11-12                   160                          1
2023-11-13                   768                          1
2023-11-14                   768                          1
2023-11-15                   768                          1
2023-11-16                   768                          1     */


Thank you very much. I updated the question, so it's better to understand what i wanted to achieve.

If you want to display items per day, you need to group by the day rather than the price. And to do that you'll need a calendar table.
In this case, to show all rows that have the minimum price for each day, I'd also use dense_rank() rather than GROUP BY.
with recursive calendar as (
    select (select min(start) from pricecache) dt
    union all 
    select dt + interval 1 day 
    from calendar 
    where dt <= (select max(end) from pricecache)
)
, ranked as ( 
    select
        date(dt) day, 
        pc.*,
        dense_rank() over (partition by date(dt) order by price) rk
    from calendar c
    inner join pricecache pc on pc.start<= date(c.dt) and pc.end >= date(c.dt)
)
select day, oid, start, end, duration, guests, child, animal, price, stamp
from ranked
where rk = 1
order by day, stamp

And then to further get the final number of items each day:
with recursive calendar as (
    select (select min(start) from pricecache) dt
    union all 
    select dt + interval 1 day 
    from calendar 
    where dt <= (select max(end) from pricecache)
)
, ranked as ( 
    select
        date(dt) day, 
        pc.*,
        dense_rank() over (partition by date(dt) order by price) rk
    from calendar c
    inner join pricecache pc on pc.start<= date(c.dt) and pc.end >= date(c.dt)
)
select day, min(price) as price, count(*) as NumberOfItems
from ranked
where rk=1
group by day
order by day

You can see them run here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/K55t94LW

But you won't see much, because the provided sample data is not meaningful: all of the price and date values are the same.
